# Java Prime Number need to be faster

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeNum {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = a ; i <= b ; i++ ) {
        if ( i == 2 || i == 3 ) System.out.println(i);

        for(int j = 2; j <= (i / 2) ; j++ ) {
            if ( (i % j) == 0 ) break;
            if ( j == (i / 2) ) System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
}
```

This program is simple, type in 2 int a and b. It will find any Prime Number within a and b.

How can I make this faster ?. I tried the Math.sqrt one but it does not work well in this case :( I do not really know because whenever I use it, it causes a lot of bugs. I would love to see someone use Squareroot in this case.

Comment: You need to read up on the Sieve of Eratosthenes - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: What buggy behavior do you see when you replace `(i/2)` with `Math.sqrt(i)`?

Comment: This is the Output when I change it ( input is 1 and 100 ) : 2
3
4
9
25
49

Comment: @SeanNersHoang: Notice that you are only getting output when the value of `i` is an exact square.

Comment: @SeanNersHoang weird, I get: `2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the suggestions to use a different approach, but I'll try to explain why your approach doesn't work.

I think the problem is in the way you are printing the result:

```
for(int j = 2; j <= (i / 2) ; j++ ) {
    if ( (i % j) == 0 ) break;
    if ( j == (i / 2) ) System.out.println(i);
}
```

This works fine for `i / 2` but it will fail for `Math.sqrt(i)` because it is not always a whole number and then `j == Math.sqrt(i)` will never be true. Your code will only work when `i` is an exact square.

It would be better to refactor your code so that your primality test is in a separate method:

```
boolean isPrime(int i) {
    int s = (int)Math.sqrt(i);
    for (int j = 2; j <= s; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also the calculation of `sqrt` is relatively expensive.  It would be a good opportunity to learn how to use a profiler to see if it matters.

Comment: thank you very much but I will go with Dan because his way is fast enought :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes algorithm. Its fast and simple to implement. Its not exactly the same, because you can not define a lowerbound (a) for that algorithm, but you can, after you found all elements from 2 to b, return just the numbers between a and b.

Answer (score 0):

How about only checking odd numbers, since even numbers very rarely are primes...

```
if(a==2) System.out.println(2);
if((a%2)==0) a++;
for(int i = a ; i <= b ; i+=2 ) {
  if(i == 3 ) System.out.println(i);
  int root = (int) Math.sqrt(i);

  for(int j = 2; j <= root ; j+=2 ) {
      if ( (i % j) == 0 ) break;
      if ( j == root ) System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```